# How to remove an element if it contains a link using querySelectorAll?

Tags: javascript, list

I tring to remove all list items that contain a link But I only remove the child element and don't know how to remove the parent.

`document.querySelectorAll('li a[href^="/chennal/robin"').forEach(e => e.remove());`

I tried to do it with loops, but it seems I'm just complicating the code for no reason, especially since it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried `e.parentNode.remove()`?

Comment: is it the same link or any `<a>`  that contains a link in `href` should be removed?

Comment: `e.closest('li').remove()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you need to walk up the DOM tree back up to the li and remove that.

You either need to use parentNode or parentElement if it is one element up.  Or closest('li') if it is more than one element up.

```js
e.parentNode.remove();
e.parentElement.remove()
e.closest('li').remove();
```

Comment: All I found was "parentNode", but since I have multiple elements on top, "e.closest('li').remove();" worked great. Thanks. The situation is in a vacuum, but what if I had 2 lists on top, can I somehow change "closest" to hide the top list, but not the closest one?

Comment: If there is a class, use that, if there is not, you can do another closest. The solution really depends on the html code.